# Recursion Using Variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently learning recursion and I've come across a website that provides solutions to certain problems. One of these problems is finding a value in an array and returning the index using recursion. The solution provided is below:

```
def searchRec2(A, k):    
   if A == []:        
      return -1    
   if A[0] == k:        
      return 0    
   recS = searchRec2(A[1:],k)    
   if recS == -1:     
      return -1    
   return recS + 1
```

What I don't understand from this code is when the code uses the variable `recS` to run each recursive call of the search, once it finds the corresponding value in the array would it not return 0, and that 0 would be stored in `recS`.

So when it does the last return statement of `recS + 1`, is it not just doing 0 + 1 which is 1? I don't understand how it gets a value other than 1. (The code works it gives the index of the element we are looking for in the array.)

Comment: run through the example on a piece of paper with a small array say `A = [2,3,4,5]` and `k=2`. Write down and keep track of the variables & you will see how they change at each recursion.

Comment: As a side note I would suggest replacing `if A == []` with `if not A` which is more Python and also faster (than a more complex list comparison).

Comment: See also [how variables are stored and treated in recursion function in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42205351/12892)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With these types of problems, it is best to use a small example to see what is happening.  Take `A = [1,2,3]` and `k = 3`.  (Answer will be 2)
Since the function calls itself, this occurs:
[image: Recursive Case Description]

When the value is found, 0 is returned from the last function call.  Then, 
1 is returned from the second to the last call. 
Similarly, 2 is returned from the third to last call. (Which was our initial call)

Thus, the final return is 2.

Another way to look at it is that the function is recursively called until it finds your k value. Once it finds your value, it stops calling new functions and starts returning values.  These returns follow up the chain of function calls, increasing by 1 after each return.

You can now start to see how this can apply to larger lists!

Comment: Thank you very much, makes a lot of sense now!

Answer (score 2):

The code works on the basic principle of recursion. Every time it does not find the element at the position it will keep incrementing the value of variable `recS` by `1`. If the element is not found and it reaches at the last element then it simply returns `-1`.

I'd highly suggest you to use [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to visualize the code which you are running.

[image: PythonTutor]

Comment: Thanks for the reply makes sense now and I will definitely use PythonTutor from now on

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote or mark it as answer if it has helped.

Answer (score 0):

It would return 0 at the specific recursive call at which `k` is the first element. It could happen at the first level of recursion or somewhere further up the stack, depending on where it is on the original list. Once it's found, the previous call would send back a `0+1`; the next one up would return `0+1+1`, and so on.

I would suggest taking a simple input (e.g. a short sequence of distinct numbers) and applying the algorithm using pen and paper.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand it a lot better now

Answer (score 0):

The function searchRec checks the item at the head of the list and then calls itself recursively on the rest (the tail) of the list. So if the item is in location 5 of the list, searchRec would have called itself recursively 5 times (i.e. the recursion depth is 5). This last call returns 0, to which the previous call adds 1, and the call previous to THAT adds another 1, ... and so on back to the first call which returns 5 (we say the recursion UNWINDS).

Comment: Ty for the reply makes sense now